# Override Magento's default image storing pattern

Tags: magento

Magento stores image, by default, as

```
~/D/E/DEFAULT.jpg
```

using the first two letters of the filename to create the folder structure.  I would like to have it work a different way, but can't find anything about it on the admin backend, or through google searches.   Has anyone had experience with this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for seems to be handled in the class `Varien_File_Uploader`, so deep down in Magento in the lib/Varien folder.
There is a method `getDispretionPath($fileName)` which looks like this:

```
static public function getDispretionPath($fileName)
{
    $char = 0; 
    $dispretionPath = '';
    while (($char < 2) && ($char < strlen($fileName))) {
        if (empty($dispretionPath)) {
            $dispretionPath = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
                . ('.' == $fileName[$char] ? '_' : $fileName[$char]);
        } else {
            $dispretionPath = self::_addDirSeparator($dispretionPath)
                  . ('.' == $fileName[$char] ? '_' : $fileName[$char]);
        }
        $char ++;
    }
    return $dispretionPath;
}
```

Basically, the while loop has maximally two runs in which it adds a directory separator followed by a character (or "_" in case the character was a ".") of the filename to the `$dispretionPath` and returns that path. This method is in turn used in the `save()` method of the same class which then creates the directories:

```
$this->_dispretionPath = self::getDispretionPath($fileName);
$destinationFile.= $this->_dispretionPath;
$this->_createDestinationFolder($destinationFile);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you find this specific function?  My problem, since I'm not to Magento, is that I don't even know where to begin looking for things like this.

Comment: @swl1020 Granted, Magento is fairly complex. I have about 4 years experience programming in the Magento ecosystem now. In that time, you get to know many parts of the system pretty well and develop a feeling where to look.
I would recommend to start looking at this link and understand the basic details to get an idea of how to find things: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento

Comment: @swl1020 This is the uploader, so I guess it will only work for newly uploaded images. If you want to change the existing files, you would need to move the image files and then change the path in the database